# Developments from Charles Peirce's logic diagrams?

Tags: logic, math-history, philosophy

These last weeks I have been revisiting Charles Sanders Peirce's logical or thought diagrams (what he called, alpha, beta and gamma diagramms) and I found many of them highly interesting. Some examples are [in this paper about their history](http://www.hum.aau.dk/~poe/ARTIKLER/GammaHTML/GammaGraphs.html) and [in this essay](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Peirce.pdf). My first impression was that maybe Feynman diagrams might have found inspiration in them... I would like to know whether some mathematical development has hinged on those intuitions by Peirce, and, if so, in which way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, i do not lack info about Peirce...quite to the contrary....what I would like to know id whether some mathematicians later hinged on his proposals for certain developments.....

Comment: Please, add examples and quotes describing the system he had in mind. There are many diagrammatic notations in proof theory (e.g. Frege's sytem or more recently proof nets), so some connections may be evident if you spell the ideas. Also, directly pasted from Wikipedia: "By the later 1890s [86] he was devising existential graphs, a diagrammatic notation for the predicate calculus. Based on them are John F. Sowa's conceptual graphs and Sun-Joo Shin's diagrammatic reasoning.". So you could expand a bit your question to make your intents clearer.

Comment: http://www.hum.aau.dk/~poe/ARTIKLER/GammaHTML/GammaGraphs.html

Comment: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/Peirce.pdf

Comment: I am not interested in the parellelisms to Frege's Begriffsschrift. Rather, I would like to know about eventual development in, say, hardcore maths (or even physics) which might be traced back to Peirce.....My impresion is that Feyman's or Penrose's diagramms might have hinged on him, but that is just an impression....

Comment: Well, proof nets look a lot like these Gamma Graphs, and they owe more to Frege's work, and they are conceptually much closer to Peirce's idea. 
And what do you base your assumptions on? There are a lot of graphical notations in math (and physics), so it's more likely that such notations were inspired by closer relatives that were more widely circulated in the appropriate mathematical folklore.

Comment: Well, Peirce was a very renowned scientist at the time, with degree in Chemistry and a lot of correspondence with top mathematicians of the time (other than his own father).......

Comment: Yes I know, but the people who were interested in his works were logicians, and then proof theorists, who designed graphical languages with similar objectives and following the same intellectual tradition. But you are not interested and want a connection with Feynman diagrams, based on the fact that he had a degree in Chemistry? Good luck with that. If you were to try to link the potential influence of Peirce on Minkowski through Hilbert and his foundational programme, you may have better luck, but it still sounds like a far cry.

Comment: I am not saying that connection should be due to Peirce having a degree in Chemistry.....I am just asking whether some developments such as Feynman diagrams could be traced back to Peirce's ideas......I think Peirce has had more influence in mathematics than it is often assumed or credited for......

Answer (score 0):

The world authority on Peirce's diagrams is Zalamea:

Zalamea, Fernando. *Peirce's logic of continuity*. Docent Press, Boston, MA, 2012.

He refers to them as "existential graphs." My impression is that Peirce's work in this area is relatively unknown compared to that of Frege Dedekind and others. For this reason it may not have had that much influence. Part of Zalamea's effort seems to be to change that situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. As far as I remember, Peirce dscussed Dedekind's work on many areas. I vaguely recall he even had some correspondence (though I might be wrong here).

Comment: The problem for Peirce was that the center of mathematical activity was in Europe at the time while he was in the US.  His work may not have been reaching the people who were in a position to appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I think that might be a misperception. Europe was not so at center of it all as it likes to believe. Not even at that time.

Comment: Javier, I am happy to agree with you. But they are the ones who controlled the journals :-)

Comment: Peirc's father wrote and publshed a short book on quaternions which was well ahead of what Europeans came up with......Just an example.